# Postman not showing error in its console rather it stops the server in nodejs, express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, error-handling, postman

I am using postman with nodejs and MySQL.

**Middleware**

```
const notFound = (req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error(`Not Found -${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.status(404);
  next(error);
};
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;
  res.status(statusCode);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? null : err.stack,
  });
};
export { notFound, errorHandler };
```

here I am trying to use `notFound` and `errorHandler` for the `authUser`

```
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  let sql =
    "select @uid :=`user_id`, first_name, last_name, email from dasa_user as var, (SELECT @uid := NULL) init_var where email=?;select @finaluid:= `user_id` from user_type, (SELECT @finaluid := NULL) init_var  where user_id =@uid AND type='customer';select customer_id, password from customer where user_id =@finaluid;";
  db.query(sql, [email], (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result) {
      if (result[2][0] == null) {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("user not Found");
      } else {
        if (MatchPassword(password, result[2]["0"]["password"])) {
          res.json({
            first_name: result[0][0]["first_name"],
            last_name: result[0][0]["last_name"],
            email: result[0][0]["email"],
            userId: result[1]["0"]["@finaluid:= `user_id`"],
            customerId: result[2]["0"]["customer_id"],
            password: result[2]["0"]["password"],
            token: generateToken(result[0][0]["email"]),
          });
        } else {
          res.status(401);
          throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
        }
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
    }
 
  });
});
```

Now for this particular controller, I am accessing `api/users/signin` which is valid. But When I use something like `api/users/signin/ksds`. It does use `notFound` middleware and gives me error in postman.
 But in body If I use incorrect `password`, it should show error in postman console. But what it does it gives me error in vscode console. like this, 
[image]
And I have to refresh the server everytime.

In order to access the notFound`and`errorHandler`, I am using` app.use` in **server.js** like this,

```
app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);
```

How can I solve this? So, that this will help me in showing error in the frontend too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This errors comes in when you get empty results. You should first check the length of the results then use properties or index on it.

```
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

  const { email, password } = req.body;
  let sql =
    "select @uid :=`user_id`, first_name, last_name, email from dasa_user as var, (SELECT @uid := NULL) init_var where email=?;select @finaluid:= `user_id` from user_type, (SELECT @finaluid := NULL) init_var  where user_id =@uid AND type='customer';select customer_id, password from customer where user_id =@finaluid;";
  db.query(sql, [email], (err, result) => {

    try {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.length > 0) {
      if (result[2][0] == null) {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("user not Found");
      } else {
        if (MatchPassword(password, result[2]["0"]["password"])) {
          res.json({
            first_name: result[0][0]["first_name"],
            last_name: result[0][0]["last_name"],
            email: result[0][0]["email"],
            userId: result[1]["0"]["@finaluid:= `user_id`"],
            customerId: result[2]["0"]["customer_id"],
            password: result[2]["0"]["password"],
            token: generateToken(result[0][0]["email"]),
          });
        } else {
          res.status(401);  // this else is calling up for (If you use incorrect password)
          throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
        }
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({message: 'Results not found'}); // change this to send error message to the frontend, you can really customise it based on your needs.
     // throw new Error("Results not found"); // Now this error is thrown because you don't have results
     
    }
    } catch (error) {
       console.error(e);
    }
     
  });
});
```

> But When I use something like api/users/signin/ksds. It does use
> notFound middleware and gives me error in postman.

Because you are creating a custom error and sending it to node default error handler which does the work for you and postman receives the error message.

> But in body If I use incorrect password, it should show error in
> postman console. But what it does it gives me error in vscode console

However, in this case your are throwing an error and it is doing its job and you see that error in the console. If you don't want this behaviour follow the same flow as used above.

Check for more details: [How to handle errors in Node.js?](https://stackify.com/node-js-error-handling/)

Comment: What if I want to show the message `Invalid email or password` to the frontend?
And is there a way to not give error in the vscode console but only in the postman console because once error comes to the vscode console I have to refresh the server.

Comment: Yes, When you throw an error it crashes the current process(you can use try/catch to avoid that), you can use tool like pm2 /forever to restart the application when any such unexpected exception occurs. However, When you are sending status(401), it signifies that the user is unauthorised and along with this you should send the custom error message to the frontend if you want. check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) out